# neovim modifies end-of-line with new line character

Tags: git, neovim

I am working on a collaborative git project, where some files don't have **end-of-line** or **\n** for last line. Any time I open those files with neovim, it changes "git status" for those files with **modified**, and I manually need to **git restore**. I tried **git diff**, it shows  "\ *No newline at end of file*".  To fix that, I tried to turnoff auto correction as follows in lua-config

```lua
local options = {
  fixendofline = false,
  fixeol = false,
}
```

Still, neovim automatically fix endofline/eol every time open those files, and I need **git restore**. Which extremely annoying.

Comment: when I do `printf foo >foo; nvim foo` and then `:set eol?` it says `noendofline` and the file is not marked modified. Try it again with `-u NONE` (or `-U NONE` as appropriate) , looks like your startup files / plugins are bugged.

Comment: . . . you might be getting bitten by the `fixeol` setting, turn that off if you don't want the trailing eol added when you do make changes.

Comment: For me, if I open json file, :set eol? shows endofline, but your foo example shows noendofline. Not sure, might be some other plugins reset back to endofline for json file.

Comment: Lots of tools that want to normalize files to “Unix line endings” will do this. In the long-term for projects that are developed on Unix (Mac/Linux) it's more convenient to enforce that final newline.